NewDocumentCommand returns `-NoValue-` where there should be the inputted parameters
I am trying to define a command using \NewDocumentCommand because I want there to be two optional parameters. This is what I tried (after begin{document}):
\NewDocumentCommand{\game}{e{\adv} e{\Pi}}{\sf PrivK^{cpa}_{#1, #2}}

where \adv was defined as \mathcal{A}. When I run the command, either as $\game$ or as something like $\game[\adv][\sigtwo]$ (\sigtwo was defined as \Sigma_2), I get the same result. The result looks fine except that each value in the subscript just displays as -NoValue- instead of whatever was inputted in the command call.

Please, remember that \sf (like all similar two-letter font switches) has been deprecated for about 30 years.

See Will two-letter font style commands (\bf, \it, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?
Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

@egreg My instructor provided the "base" code, and I was just looking for a way to add some parameters to make it more flexible. Thanks for letting me know! I wonder where he got the idea of using \sf if it's been deprecated for that long. Perhaps I should tell him...

The e parameter option is reserved for ebellishments (or exponents); from the xparse documentation:

e
Given as e{<tokens>}, a set of optional embellishments, each of which
requires a value. If an embellishment is not present, -NoValue- is returned.
Each embellishment gives one argument, ordered as for the list of <tokens>
in the argument specification. All <tokens> must be distinct.

This explains why you get -NoValue- as the default as no proper embellishments were supplied as tokens. It seems like you were rather interested in Optional arguments, not embellishments:

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\adv}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\sigmatwo}{\Sigma_2}

\NewDocumentCommand{\game}{O{\adv} O{\Pi}}{\mathsf{PrivK}^{\mathrm{cpa}}_{#1, #2}}

\begin{document}

$\game$

$\game[5]$

$\game[t][\sigmatwo]$

$\game[][\sigmatwo]$

\end{document}

Note the issue with the final example of \game[][\sigmatwo]: To specify the second optional argument you necessarily have to supply a first optional argument. This doesn't really make them optional. For multiple optional components, it's better to use a key-value approach.

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\adv}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\sigmatwo}{\Sigma_2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { user1181399/game }
{
  first  .tl_set:N = {\l__game_first}, % first argument
  second .tl_set:N = {\l__game_second}, % second argument
  first  .initial:n = \adv, % first argument default
  second .initial:n = \Pi % second argument default
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\game}{ O{} }
 {%
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { user1181399/game } {#1}% Set default keys (locally)
  \mathsf{PrivK}^{\mathrm{cpa}} \c_math_subscript_token {\l__game_first, \l__game_second}%
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\game$

$\game[first = 5]$

$\game[first = t, second = \sigmatwo]$

$\game[second = \sigmatwo]$

\end{document}

